# Lock a cell based on another cell's entry

Tags: validation, checkbox, google-sheets

I am building an inspection sheet in Google Sheets and have a column with a checkbox for fail and a column with a checkbox for a pass.

How do I lock one cell when the other is checked to not allowed double-checking.

**Screenshot of the Google-Sheet, any help appreciated.**

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Why have two checkboxes when one would do? Then apply conditional formatting depending on whether the checkbox is ticked or not ticked.

Answer (score 0):

this can't be done because you would need to apply a Data validation rules for both columns, but the issue is that checkbox is a type of Data validation rule so by adding additional Data validation rules it would destroy the checkbox.